# Django TypeError in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, modelform

I am just trying to render a ModelForm and I keep getting the following error:

"TypeError: EditManifestSelect.Meta.fields cannot be a string. Did you mean to type: ('reference',)?"

I did indeed try to type it as suggested above, but just continue to receive the same error. Any Ideas?

FORMS.PY

```
class EditManifestSelect(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Manifests
        fields = ('reference')
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def edit_manifest(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditManifestSelect(request.POST)


        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('display_orders')
    else:
        form = EditManifestSelect()
        return render(request, 'edit_manifest.html', {'form': form})
```

MODELS.PY

```
class Manifests(models.Model):

    reference = models.ForeignKey(Orders)
    cases = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    count = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cases
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code of forms.py as follows.

```
class EditManifestSelect(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Manifests
        fields = ('reference', )
```

Comment: yes I've done that, but I continue to get the same exact error. I've actually fixed it now though, for some reason I had to kill the server and reboot.